# PHP: search and remove JSON object

Tags: php, json

I have a quite nested JSON file. How can I delete an array that includes my value? For ex: I want to delete `{"customer":"Customer1","date":"2017-06-03"...}` from JSON file and I already knew the **"Customer1"**

```
{
            "info": [{
                "customer": "Customer1",
                "date": "2017-06-03",
                "beacons": [{
                    "data1": "1234",
                    "data2": "Test1",
                }, {
                    "data1": "0088",
                    "data2": "Test2",
                }]
            },{
                "customer": "Customer2",
                "date": "2017-06-03",
                "beacons": [{
                    "data1": "dcdd4",
                    "data2": "Test3",
                }, {
                    "data1": "0088",
                    "data2": "Test4",
                }]
            }]
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly you want to do, share your code with proper explanation. Otherwise we would end up assuming things.

Comment: do you want to do it through jQuery or php?

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu PHP please

Comment: @AmitRajput: I don't know how to do it in PHP. What I thought were loop and unset. But it looks quite confused. Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some issue in your json data. This is not valid json data; I have decoded the josn data & then check if "customer" value = 'Customer1', then remove the array from main array.

It should be like this:

```
$jsonData = '{"info ": [{
    "customer ": "customer1 ",
    "date ": "2017 - 06 - 03 ",
    "beacons ": [{
        "data1 ": "1234",
        "data2 ": "Test1"
    }]
}, {
    "customer": "customer2 ",
    "date": "2017 - 06 - 04 ",
    "beacons": [{
        "data1": "dcdd4",
        "data2": "Test3"
    }]
 }]
}';

$myData = json_decode($jsonData,true);


foreach($myData["info"] as $k=>$arr) {
    if($arr["customer"] == "customer1") {
       unset($myData["info"][$k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dipanwita, but I don't know if there is any mistake in my JSON file makes it doesn't work

Comment: There are errors near "beacon" Please compare it with my json data. on you can cross check in "http://jsoneditoronline.org" also.

Answer (score 0):

make the object to assign to one obj example :=>

```
var myobj={"info": [{ ...... }]}
```

.this below function will work for the searching the exact value in object array 
call the function with the parameters as like below

```
searchObj (myobj, Customer1);

function searchObj (obj_name, searchingval) {
    for (var key in obj_name) {
        var value = obj_name[key];

        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            searchObj(value, searchingval);
        }

        if (value === searchingval) {
            console.log('property name=' + key + '    property value=' + value);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one small correction in the previous answer .

please call function like this . the searching value should be a value like astring format .

```
searchObj (myobj, 'Customer1');
```